# IIS Smooth Streaming encoding with Azure?

Tags: azure, expression, smooth-streaming

I'm working on a project for teachers and students to be able to have a medium to interact with one another using Azure as a medium for content delivery. However, since this is basically a free service (and a non-profit site), not every teacher can buy a copy of Encoder Pro to encode their streams.

This is where I'm at a crossroads and not sure what path to go down. I want teachers to be able to stream their desktops and interact with students, probably using the MSN chat services or facebook chat services since it's infrastructure that I don't need to pay for. However, additionally the question is how do they capture their desktop? And would Azure be able to convert that into a "smooth streaming" file, so that people with lower bandwith connections can see the stream reliabily? I know Azure can function as a CDN, but I'm not sure if it can do the conversion to live smooth streaming so that students can actually make use of the service.

Any ideas would be helpful.. I'm kind of brainstorming right now and working on the client end of things, but I've slowed down until I can figure out this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear in your question - are you looking for live smooth streaming in real-time, or on-demand smooth streaming where a teacher pre-records content and the students view it whenever it's ready?

Answer (score 1):

To answer part of your question, Azure recently added a Media Services component. It's still in preview mode (free for now). Think of it as a hosted Expression Encoder Pro exposed with a bunch of APIs. For more info https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services/